# DataFlow Export Duplicate SKUs in SKU Field

Tags: magento-1.9, database, upgrade, dataflow, ce-1.9.2.0

I use the DataFlow Import/Export on a daily basis for updating product information. Last week we upgraded to the new 1.9.2 from 1.9.1 and besides the many other issues this upgrade has caused, now I am getting duplicates SKUs exporting and when I try to import to update pricing, the import freezes. I've attached an image!

[image: "Export"]

Comment: Are there actual duplicates in the Catalog or only when you export?

Comment: Only when I export. And the only field that is duplicated is SKU...Some repeat and some don't..like the MM101. I'm thinking this may be something to do with the amount of times that product was edited? I recently truncated the index_event and index_process_event... Could this have caused this?

Comment: the issue is related to this function `Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Parser_Product::unparse()`: in >1.9.0 looks they added some extra code to export the images.
Using the 1.9.0 version on of this file is perfect safe as the only difference in the code is the one that cause the issue

Answer (score 3):

When you update to Magento 1.9.2.X you will have this problem. If u use the app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Parser/Products.php from a older version of magento it will fix your problem.

You can try using this link, its a temporary fix that uses a older Products.php file:

https://github.com/baconl/Magento-1.9.2.1-duplicate-sku-fix

Keep in mind, this is a temporary fix until the magento core team fixes it in the next version of Magento.

Comment: Heh, modularize it and make it permanent, everyone's over there tearing their hair out making the latest Magento 2.x function and we won't be seeing this or other minor 1.x issues being revisited.